U.S. Highway 24 Mile-Marker Oddity in Colorado
As per U.S. Route 24 (Wikipedia), the western terminus of U.S. 24 is located near Minturn, CO, where it joins with Interstate 70.

Having just driven this road, I noticed that the western-most highway milepost marker was "143," not the expected "0".
Why is this?

It is likely because it originally started from Grand Junction, 143 miles from Minturn.

@xngtng That may be it! If you have one or more good sources, please expand your statement into an actual answer.

This is pretty common for older highways which were partly overlaid by interstates. Sometimes the old US route is overlaid (usually if it joins for a bit and then diverges), sometimes as here the old US number is dropped if no longer needed.

From Wikipedia's article on US Route 24:

When the U.S. Numbered Highway System was started in 1926, US 24 in Colorado was designated US 40S. It began in Grand Junction and went east along the current I-70 corridor to Minturn, from which it followed the current route to Limon. From Limon east to the Kansas border, the current US 24 was designated US 40N. US 40S west of Limon and US 40N east of Limon received the US 24 designation in 1936, when US 24 was extended west from Kansas City, Missouri.  The segment between Grand Junction and Minturn was decommissioned in 1975.

In addition, the AAroads website notes that

U.S. 24 historically ran west alongside U.S. 6 from Dowd [close to Minturn – ed.] to U.S. 50 at Grand Junction. The long concurrency was eliminated with approval by the American Association of State Highway and Transportation Officials (AASHTO) on November 15, 1975.

So when US-24 was originally designated in 1936, it ran concurrently with US-6 from Grand Junction to Minturn (143 miles away).  In 1975, this westernmost segment of the highway was "de-designated" from US-24.  It seems likely that the mile markers were simply left as they were when this was done, resulting in US-24 "starting" at mile 143.
Finally, a scan taken from a 1975 edition of the Rand-McNally Road Atlas:

This appears to show US-24 entering Grand Junction but not leaving it, suggesting that this was the terminus of US-24 at the time.

The above comment on Wikipedia is unsourced, so you might want to wait a few days before accepting this answer in case someone comes up with a more authoritative answer.  (If you do want to accept it, of course — don't want to presume.)

Here is another reference if you want to elaborate (search for AASHTO): U.S. 24. For another interesting comment, search for milepost 143 on that same page...

In addition, U.S. 24 in CO shows that there is a non-zero milepost at the western terminus...

@Digger:  Edited to incorporate the AAroads website information.  Thanks!

paper map !!!!!
